# How to wake up a locked screen remotely? vnc viewer: send C-A-D doesn't work

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, vncserver, realvnc, vnc-viewer

I am remotely controlling a windows pc by VNC viewer. Unfortunately, the screen of that pc is locked up, though the system is still running. So I can see how the programs on it running, but I cannot click any button on the screen.

The server is a PC, the viewer is a remote desk in a cloud. So I need to login into a remote desktop, on which I connect to the remote pc(server) using VNC Viewer.

Is there any way to unlock the screen of pc remotely? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by locked, but I can log onto a remote computer via Teamviewer as long as I have the p/w.
It may be a config on the remote PC that only allows viewing. Teamviewer has a View and Show option (which I have never used) as opposed to full access that may be your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Here in my viewer I can watch the desk and the programs but I cannot access to them(cannot stop the programs or open any file), so I know that the remote pc must be SCREEN-LOCKED, in which case I have to input the password to unlock the screen.